When should I normalize my QAM constellation for a fading channel?
I am trying to simulate a Fading channel and learning from matlab and python codes online.
I am not very sure when should I normalize my constellation and I am getting very different results when I normalized my QAM constellation.
When using a normalized QAM constellation by $N_0$ is defined as,
$$N_0 = \frac{1}{E_b/N_0 \log_2 M}$$
But when not using a normalized constellation my $N_0$ is defined as,
$$N_0 = \frac{E_s}{E_b/N_0 \log_2 M}$$


Normalization, if done correctly, should not have impact in BER simulation. This must be simply an implementation issue.
